# (When) Is it a security concern if BIOS/UEFI uses/reserves much RAM?

Tags: memory, firmware, bios

BIOS, UEFI and hardware's firmware ROMs are not very comforting sources for concern. On a system that I administer, a large amount of main system memory (9 of 512GB) is unavailable.

Next to the unfortunate loss of a valuable resource (main memory), I am concerned with the question how to evaluate this "opaque" memory that has been handed over to the `UEFI/BIOS`?

What is a normal memory footprint a system **firmware** should be, that would not be an instant *raising-eye-brow* with regard to security considerations?

Comment: That's going to depend on the system...

Comment: Except for making system management calls, UEFI doesn't acquire RAM when host OS is running.

Comment: @schroeder is there a way for me to formulate my question in a way that is less depending on context "system". My concrete concern is a Dell Poweredge R7425 where linux ends up with 9GiB of 512GiB main memory being not available. I distrust SMM and firmware. Memory not available to the kernel seems a danger

Comment: Sure, the answer is drop-dead simple: "if the memory it takes is different from baseline". But no BIOS uses 9GB... You either don't have full visibility, you are interpreting something wrong, or malware is taking up a system's worth of RAM to do something very memory-intensive. I'd rule out the former before assuming the latter.